# titanium animation doesn't retain its values

Tags: javascript, android, ios, mobile, titanium

When I'm animating on Titanium a view, it doesn't retain its values. Let say for example I have a view named `bar` with `height=0`. I would like to animate so I made this code..

```
aniBar1 = Ti.UI.createAnimation({
    curve: Ti.UI.ANIMATION_CURVE_EASE_OUT,
    duration : 250,
    height : 50,
    top : 0
});

bar.animate(aniBar1);
```

This do the trick but when I do the second animation after some events, lets say

```
aniBar2 = Ti.UI.createAnimation({
    curve: Ti.UI.ANIMATION_CURVE_EASE_OUT,
    duration : 250,
    height : 150,
    top : 0
 });
```

I want it to animate from the height 50 to 150 but it doesn't do that. When I execute second animation. It shrink down to 0 do the animation.

Is there a way to retain the values when animating? I tried to set the new values on callback but I can do callbacks.

Your help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: which Titanium SDK you are using?

Comment: @Swanand I'm using it for Android Titanium version 7.1403

Comment: @Eddie I am asking about Titanium SDK version, because its working perfectly fine on my system.

Comment: @Swanand Ohh.. the sdk is 3.2.0 GA

Answer (score 1):

you need to set new value in its complete event...

```
aniBar1 = Ti.UI.createAnimation({
    curve: Ti.UI.ANIMATION_CURVE_EASE_OUT,
    duration : 250,
    height : 50,
    top : 0
});
aniBar1.addEventListener('complete',function(e){
        bar.height = 50;
});

bar.animate(aniBar1);
```

Comment: Yes this would work but i cant use a call back function. Any more suggestion?

Comment: but what is the problem to use callback?